# asdf install [warning] /usr/bin/fop Fop is missing. Using fakefop to generate placeholder PDF files

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, asdf-vm

When installing Erlang using asdf version manager, the above build warning indicates that the [apache fop library](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) has either not been installed on the system, or has not been recognised by the asdf version manager. The result is that the Erlang documentation will not be installed as a part of the installation.

Error encountered when executing the following command:

```
asdf install erlang <version>
```

Answer (score 4):

This error is related to the fact that you **MUST** abide by the platform requirements listed in the [asdf Erlang extension page](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang).

Personally, I'm using MATE on Ubuntu 18.10 - Cosmic Cuttlefish. To satisfy the asdf runtime requirements for Ubuntu, I needed to install the following [Check the Erlang extension page for your specific platform's requirements](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang):

```
sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0-0v5 \
    libwxbase3.0-dev \
    libwxgtk3.0-0v5 \
    libwxgtk3.0-dev \
    libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 \
    libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev \
    wx3.0-doc \
    wx3.0-examples \
    wx3.0-headers \
    wx3.0-i18n \
    wx-common \
    libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-0v5 \
    libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev \
    libwxgtk-media3.0-0v5 \
    libwxgtk-media3.0-dev \
    libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-0v5 \
    libwxgtk-media3.0-gtk3-dev
```

Once you have satisfied the platform requirements, you can safely go ahead and re-process the asdf Erlang installation successfully with the following syntax:

```
 asdf install erlang <version>
```

If after completing the installation the documentation has still not been installed, check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041920/asdf-erlang-doesnt-install-man-pages) for assistance with this

Comment: The macos requirements only mention autoconf.

Comment: Ditto I'm having exactly the same problem after installing the two requirements autoconf and wxmac and still getting the issue.

Comment: `brew install fop` adds the `fop` command to your PATH. This makes the warning go away when run `asdf install erlang 24.0.6`. 
Without the `fop` package installed the warning is shown.